# excel sheet daily /weekly/monthly reports in an windows application format

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I have this excel sheet which needs to  be modified every day I am trying to export it to windows application and want to have database for it but i cant understand `how to create a table with this format  in sql and  how can i query on the table.` I want it to display it as dashboard. Any light on this would be helpful.

this is my code:

```
private static Excel.Workbook MyBook = null; 
private static Excel.Application MyApp = null;
private static Excel.Worksheet MySheet = null;

MyApp = new Excel.Application();
MyApp.Visible = false;
MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(DB_PATH);
MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1]; // Explicit cast is not required here
lastRow = MySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;
```

[image].

Comment: this is a very broad question... i recommend you see some tutorials about building a database, exporting data to database, reading database and obiously SQL syntax etc

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood your problem. If you have a problem getting the day in week for a given date try this (sql server):

```
select datename(dw,getdate()) --Tuesday
```

You could just have a datetime field in your database and use the query above to fill the "NAME" header of your excel sheet.